Google App Engine - disable a single page/script from console
I have a page (a new user signup page) which is being attacked. While I work on the fix and security, is there a way I can disable this one page/url/script from within the console rather than deploy a change?

I don't think there is a way to disable a particular page/url/script from the console. I understand that you want to delete a user signup page script or url of it from the console without interrupting the deployment process. But the app engine console is mainly for managing infrastructure, application's performance and resources utilization.
It’s difficult to give the exact solution but you may check for the App engine application logs.
To avoid this kind of security issues, and fixing those issues have a look at this Documentation.

Security is a core feature of the Google Cloud, but there are still steps you should take to protect your App Engine app and identify vulnerabilities. The features in the Documentation ensure that your App Engine app is secure.

Once you configure the security feature to your application, you have the feasibility to secure URL access. Have a look at this Stackoverflow Link.
Also it's better to Contact support as you mentioned I have a page (a new user signup page) which is being attacked to control further security issues and it may require project-inspection.
